# Declared string inside class keeps reverting to original value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Brand new to swift.

I'm running into a problem where a declared string inside a class keeps reverting back to its original value after I modify it.

```
class Calculation: ObservableObject {
    var CalcString: String = "test"
    
    func modifyCalcString(newData: String) {
        CalcString = CalcString + newData
        print(CalcString)
    }
}
```

`modifyCalcString` is called using a button in an app view

```
Calculation().modifyCalcString(newData: digit)
```

*(digit is a string)*

my problem is every time I call modifyCalcString it is modified and then reverts back to its original value.

for example when calling modifyCalString with newData as "5" the print statement inside the function will output "test5" but after printing it again it reverts back to "test"

im pretty lost here and would appreciate the help.

Comment: hmm is the mutated instance stored anywhere so it can be used next time?

Comment: You should make `CalcString` private.

Comment: Also worth noting: The Swift convention is to reserve `UpperCamelCase` for type names, exclusively. Also, `calcString = calcString + newData` can just be written as `calcString += newData`

Comment: `Calculation()` is short for `Calculation.init()`, meaning you are creating a NEW object/instance. So if you do that multiple times, of courses, you'll have each time a new object with initial string value to be `"test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for this is that you are not working with the same class instance every time.

Comment: yep I kept initializing the class over and over again. Thanks!